# How to use nrwl nx tools (for angular) with bitbucket pipelines to utilize nx affected?

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines, nrwl-nx

I am having an existing angular project using Nrwl nx workspace. For CI I am using bitbucket pipelines.
nx has very helpful feature of nx affected which allows running targets like test/lint/build etc based only on the changes.
Also in bitbucket pipelines, I am till now using parallel steps for running tests on multiple libraries in parallel.
e.g from bitbucket-pipelines.yml files

```
- parallel:
      # parallel execution
      - step: *test-lib1
      - step: *test-lib2
      - step: *test-lib3
```

Now what I am trying to do is to run tests on affected libraries in the pipeline - using below command to get the list of affected libraries

```
npx nx print-affected --target=test --base=master --select="tasks.target.project"
```

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone landing here from search enging try `npx nx affected --target=test --base=master`.

This should run the `test` target on all the affected projects.